# The backbone router isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm building a simple backbone app that have 4 routes: home, about, privacy and terms. But after setting the routes I have 3 problems:

The "terms" view isn't rendering;

When I refresh the #about or the #privacy page, the home view renders after the #about/#privacy view

When I hit the back button the home view never renders. For example, if I'm in the #about page, and I hit the back button to the homepage, the about view stays in the page

I don't know what I'm doing wrong about the 1st problem. I think that the 2nd and 3rd problem are related with something missing in the home router, but I don't know what is.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<section class="feed">

    <script id="homeTemplate" type="text/template">

        <div class="home">
        </div>

    </script>

    <script id="termsTemplate" type="text/template">

        <div class="terms">
        Bla bla bla bla
        </div>

    </script>   

    <script id="privacyTemplate" type="text/template">

        <div class="privacy">   
        Bla bla bla bla
        </div>

    </script>

    <script id="aboutTemplate" type="text/template">

         <div class="about">
         Bla bla bla bla
         </div>

    </script>

</section>
```

The views

```
app.HomeListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.feed',

    initialize: function ( initialbooks ) {
         this.collection = new app.BookList (initialbooks);
         this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
         this.collection.each(function( item ){
         this.renderHome( item );
         }, this);
    },

    renderHome: function ( item ) {
         var bookview = new app.BookView ({
         model: item
         })
         this.$el.append( bookview.render().el );
         }  });

app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'home', 

     template: _.template( $( '#homeTemplate' ).html()),

    render: function() {
         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
         return this;
         }  
 });

app.AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
     tagName: 'div',
     className: 'about',

     initialize:function () {
         this.render();
     },

     template: _.template( $( '#aboutTemplate' ).html()),

     render: function () {
         this.$el.html(this.template());
         return this;
     }
});

 app.PrivacyView = Backbone.View.extend ({
     tagName: 'div',
     className: 'privacy',

     initialize: function() {
         this.render();
     },

     template: _.template( $('#privacyTemplate').html() ),

     render: function () {
         this.$el.html(this.template());
         return this;
     }
});

 app.TermsView = Backbone.View.extend ({
     tagName: 'div',
     className: 'terms',

     initialize: function () {
         this.render();
     },

     template: _.template ( $( '#termsTemplate' ).html() ), 

     render: function () {
         this.$el.html(this.template()),
         return this;
     }
 });
```

And the router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         '' : 'home',
         'about' : 'about',
         'privacy' : 'privacy',
         'terms' : 'terms'
     },

     home: function () {
         if (!this.homeListView) {
             this.homeListView = new app.HomeListView();
         };
     },

     about: function () {
         if (!this.aboutView) {
             this.aboutView = new app.AboutView();
        };
         $('.feed').html(this.aboutView.el);
     },

     privacy: function () {
         if (!this.privacyView) {
             this.privacyView = new app.PrivacyView();
         };
         $('.feed').html(this.privacyView.el);
     },

     terms: function () {
          if (!this.termsView) {
             this.termsView = new app.TermsView();
         };
         $('.feed').html(this.termsView.el);
     }
 })

 app.Router = new AppRouter();
 Backbone.history.start();
```

I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to move your script templates out of your .feed html element, when you render the HomeListView view it will remove everything inside its el, then the script templates will be unavailable to the other views that you are calling iside of the HomeListView.

```
<section class="feed">



</section>
<script id="homeTemplate" type="text/template">

    <div class="home">
    </div>

</script>

<script id="termsTemplate" type="text/template">

    <div class="terms">
    Bla bla bla bla
    </div>

</script>   

<script id="privacyTemplate" type="text/template">

    <div class="privacy">   
    Bla bla bla bla
    </div>

</script>

<script id="aboutTemplate" type="text/template">

     <div class="about">
     Bla bla bla bla
     </div>

</script>
```

also you are missing a colon in the render function for the termsView

```
  render: function () {
     this.$el.html(this.template());
     return this;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your suggestion bu I'm still having the same issues.

Comment: also you are missing a colon in the render function for the termsView

Comment: The error in the console is this one: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return. Where I'm missing a colon in the termsView?

Comment: in your render function you are missing it at this line  this.$el.html(this.template()),

Comment: I already discovered the missing colon. So the 1st problem is solved. Thanks! Now I need to solve the other 2 problems

Comment: There are no erros in the console

Comment: are you familiar with jsfiddle? if you can paste your code there will be great. so we can debug it there.

Comment: Yep I'm familiar with jsfiddle. Here is the link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/Mm8Mt/ Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say that at the end of the code I have this to test the app: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/rBh2L/ and maybe some part of that code is related with my problems

Answer (score 2):

In addition to everything suggested by Rayweb_on, remove the call to `render` from the `initialize` methods of `AboutView`, `PrivacyView` and `TermsView` and in your route functions, replace `$('.feed').html(this.aboutView.el);`, etc. with `$('.feed').html(this.aboutView.render().el);`, etc.

Also, define a variable in your router called `currentView` or something like that and set it to whatever view your route functions choose. In each route function, check if it's been set and if so, call `remove()` on it before rendering the new view. These changes should keep previously-rendered views from stepping on new ones and make sure that the newly-rendered view is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I set currentView to whatever view the route functions choose and how can I check if each route function it's been set and call remove() before render the new view? I'm sorry but I'm still learning Backbone, so more help is always welcome. Thanks